# How to find similar data from pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

[My raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMCpB.png)
I want to find all **Imaging** data(that is under column 'method') from dataframe and printout related value.
I want something like this.
[expecting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCydY.png)

Comment: please copy and paster your dataframe of exampe, we can use `pd.read_clipboard` to work with example and then we be able to help you

Comment: It seems you just want to filter the dataframe object... Have you tried something?

Comment: `new_df = curent_df.loc[curent_df['method'] == 'Imaging']`?

Comment: :import seaborn as sns
planets = sns.load_dataset('planets')

Comment: Thank you @ManojK Sir